# Styling Tumblr mobile version

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

I downloaded Tumblr mobile app and im trying to make some customizations to my blog, but it seems that i can only do the most basic stuff (add/remove image and text).
I was wondering is it possible to access the HTML/CSS of the theme so i can make my changes directly to the code?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: More info on the mobile theme: http://staff.tumblr.com/post/536753754/optimized-iphone-layout I am not 100% sure if this applies to the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can only edit the theme of the [mobile layout](http://staff.tumblr.com/post/536753754/optimized-iphone-layout) which is used for mobile browsers, the app can't be change apart from the colour of your blog's header, the title and the description.